# Symfony custom validator as service

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-2.3

Trying to follow the custom validator as as service example from the official docs . I have defined my validator as a service in my "services.yml":

```
cf.validator.unique.in.system:
            class: 'CF\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueInSystemValidator'
            arguments: ['@doctrine']
            tags:
                - { name: 'validator.constraint_validator', alias: 'cf.validator.unique.in.system' }
```

I have created the neccesary constraint and validator classes:

**constraint**

```
namespace CF\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueInSystem extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This value is already used.';

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT;
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'cf.validator.unique.in.system';
    }
}
```

**validator**

```
namespace CF\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class UniqueInSystemValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected  $em;

    public  function  __construct(Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->em = $doctrine->getManager();
    }
    public function validate($subsystem, Constraint $constraint)
    {

        1==1; // here is a breakpoint by now
//        $this->context->addViolationAt('[expiresAt].expiresAt', $constraint->message, ['%string%' => $value->format('Y-m-d')] );
    }
```

What I do not understand, is the error message that I get:`FatalErrorException: Error: Class '\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CF\AppBundle\Validators\Constraints\UniqueInSystem' not found in /var/www/escritorio.dev/application/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php line 89`

Especially this part: `'\Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CF\AppBundle\Validators\Constraints\UniqueInSystem'`. Why symfony tries to search in this weird namespace? How to avoid this issue?

### UPD

The validator itself is applied via `/src/CF/AppBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml`:

```
CF\AppBundle\Entity\SubSystem:
  constraints:
      - CF\AppBundle\Validators\Constraints\UniqueInSystem: ~
  properties:
    name:
      - NotBlank: ~
      - Length:
          max: 100
    owner:
      - NotBlank: ~
    leader:
      - NotBlank: ~
    system:
      - NotBlank: ~
    status:
      - NotBlank : ~
      - Type:
          type: integer
```

The `app/console container:debug` output:

```
$ php app/console container:debug  | grep CF
auc_helper                                         container CF\AppBundle\Services\AucHelper
cf.validator.unique.in.system                      container CF\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueInSystemValidator
```

Comment: Could you check please what will be the result of class_exists('CF\AppBundle\Validators\Constraints\UniqueInSystem') (somewhere in controller)

Comment: Are you sure `cf.validator.unique.in.system` is properly injected to the container? If symfony cannot find validator by alias it will try to include class with the provided validator name.

Comment: The problem is in the way you are using the constraint.  I'm guessing you need a use statement.  Update your question with an example of how you are trying to apply the constraint.

Comment: I checked the service container within the `app/console container:debug` and I see it loaded

Comment: Added the usage example, and output from container:debug

Comment: Hint: Validators vs Validator.

Comment: @Cerad can you explain? I did not get what you meant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// This
CF\AppBundle\Entity\SubSystem:
  constraints:
    - CF\AppBundle\Validators\Constraints\UniqueInSystem: ~

// Should be
CF\AppBundle\Entity\SubSystem:
  constraints:
    - CF\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueInSystem: ~
```

It's always been a bit of a mystery as to why the Constraints directory is not called Constraint.  But Validator has always been called Validator.